# why some new elements in HTML5 still have presentation applied?

Tags: html, css

As my understanding, One of goals that HTML5 wants to achieve is to separate elements' presentation from semantics meaning. So we only use style sheet(e.g css) to style elements. And for previous elements before HTML5, we still keep presentation for backward compatibility. But they are some new HTML elements still have presentation style by itself. For example, `mark` element is new to HTML5 and represents a span of text that is highlighted due to its relevance in another context, so if I use it as:

```
<p>
 I would like a <mark>pair</mark> of <mark>pears</mark>
</p>
```

pair and pears will be highlighted in yellow, isn't that against HTML5 design which needs a separate style sheet to apply presentation effects?

Comment: the browser interprets HTML by itself, so when a style is missing in stylesheets they apply their own default style to elements

Comment: The goal was to assign semantics to every element and not keep elements solely for presentational purposes. That doesn’t mean that elements aren’t allowed to have a default presentation. They just can’t have _nothing but_ their presentation. `<mark>` has clearly defined semantics.

Answer (score 3):

In a similar fashion as to why list items such as:

- One
- Two
- Three

Have default styling  (a *disc* or filled circle, with some amount of indentation), `<mark>` or any element should also have a default styling. Same with `<pre>` for fixed width preformatted text.

If not, in some sense you wouldn't be able to notice the `<mark>` text (or any other style) if you only opened an HTML file without any CSS styling.

As to how they decide, [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/text-level-semantics.html#the-mark-element) doesn't seem to say that it's supposed to be a bright yellow background on top of the text.

Seems that browser vendors just agree to agree (or secretly meet somewhere in a safehouse in Antarctica where they discuss this), but if someone has the right answer to this it would be great to know it.

**EDIT:** Do note that some of the default styling can be edited in your browser such as colors, font size and family, etc. In Firefox it looks like this:

[image: Settings]

I did it once for a full month just to see how well websites fared with it. Needless to say, the whole internet broke and was starting to have panic attacks (I have OCD in regards to well-written CSS).